# How to deduce the formula for quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I almost every book about quadratic form we can see it described as following function:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x - b^Tx + c
$$

**My question** is:

How can we deduce this formula?

---

I understand, that the quadratic form is the following product:

$$
Q( \boldsymbol{x} ) = \boldsymbol{x}^TA \boldsymbol{x}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a vector, $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $\boldsymbol{x},A$ are defined over $F$, where $F$ is some arbitrary field (except those, who have a characteristic $2$).

This product can be rewritten by summation like this:

$$
Q \left(\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \right) = \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^n_{j=1} A_{ij}x_i x_j
$$

I understand, that because the matrix is symmetric $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$, so when I want to get the value for one $x$, I must divide it by $2$. That's exactly the first part of the polynomial:

$$
\frac{1}{2}x^T A x
$$

But, where do $-b^T + c$ come from? I think, that it's related with the linear system $A \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{b}$, but I have no idea, how to use it in this deduction...

Comment: There are various garblings here. The function $f$ as written is not, in general, a quadratic form, as $f(0)$ is in general nonzero. Also, presumably the second term should be $b^T x$, not $b^T$. Next, $Q(x) = x^T A x$, when the underlying field is real, need not be positive (consider when $A = -I$). For a general field $F$, the inequality is usually not defined. Moreover, $A$ is a matrix in $M(n, F)$, not (presumably) an element of $F$, i.e., a scalar.

Comment: Could you cite which book you've seen the above formula (the first one)?

Comment: Ok, seems like I need a really thorough explanation :-) ... I read about function $f$ for example in [this article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) - page 2, equation 3. I defined the inequality to make sure, that the matrix $A$ is positive-definite (previous article, page 2, equation 2). And I'm sorry, the last thing is obviously just my  inaccuracy.

Comment: I've tried to correct the mistake with $A$ being defined over $F$.

Comment: hint : consider replacing $x$ with $x-x_0$, you can do so as to "absorb" the $b$ .

Comment: Judging from the article, I think that equation is a *definition*?

Comment: @awllower It is, but I think it must be a deduction of something, not just a postulate :-)

Comment: @Eenoku It's odd, it seems they're using the extra terms of the quadratic form to relocate its minimum point. This is similar to what happens when you consider the parabola $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. All parabolas are similar, so in theory, you could write $p(x) = q(kx - u) + v$ where $q(x) = x^2$. Since the paper revolves around an application, it might have been to their benefit to define quadratic forms not centered at $0$. You could potentially apply the same logic of the parabola in one dimension to the quadratic form in many dimensions.

Comment: @Eenoku Ok, I think this might be related to the binary quadratic form $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2?$ After the homogenization your form becomes a binary quadratic form, but the rest of the article does not seem to employ of this... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then the general quadratic function is:

$f(x_1,x_2)=a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+a_{12}x_1x_2+b_1x_1+b_2x_2+c$

The first three summnads can be expressed by $\frac12 x^TAx$ with $A=\begin{pmatrix}{} 2a_1 &a_{12} \\ a_{12} & 2a_2\end{pmatrix}$

The fourth and the fifth summand are $b^Tx=\begin{pmatrix}{}b_1 & b_2\end{pmatrix}\cdot  \begin{pmatrix}{} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$

And $c$ is a scalar (constant).

Calculate $\frac12x^TAx+b^Tx+c$ and you´ll get $f(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: Ok, I understand this... But, where did you get the part $b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + c$? I mean, how is your "general quadratic function" deduced?

Comment: @Eenoku To make it short see the link. But it is obvious if you have two variables that each has not more than degree of 2. And then you decrease the exponents with all combinations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form

Comment: Great! Could you, please, add this info into your answer,  so I could accept it?